# Citizenship for two children from ghana

Tags: citizenship

I have two children, under 10 years old, born in Ghana and would like to know how to register them as British citizens. I, the father, am a British citizen by birth and the mother is a Ghanaian citizen. Can they possess dual citizenship?

Comment: A British citizen "by birth" specifically refers to someone born in the UK before 1983, or after 1983 to at least one parent who was a British citizen or permanent resident. Is that what you are?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the births have been registered locally you can also register the births with the UK authorities. You don’t need to do this but it means:

- the birth will be recorded with the General Register Offices or at the National Records Office of Scotland
- you can order a consular birth registration certificate
  https://www.gov.uk/register-a-birth

You can still apply for a UK passport for your children even if you don’t register the birth in the UK.

Ghana permits dual citizenship https://www.ghanahighcommissionuk.com/dual-citizenship-application/

Comment: @RichardReid this answer makes the assumption that you are a British citizen "otherwise than by descent." If that is true then your children are already British citizens (by descent). If, however, *you* are a British citizen "by descent," that is, by birth outside the UK and its territories, this answer does not apply, because in that case the children are not British citizens.